# Are the downloaded map legend units different than those in the online data explorer?

Tags: soilgrids

I have just recently downloaded the 0.05m depth CEC map from SoilGrids and noticed that the map units do not match those in the WMS version, or those in the file explorer online (even if divided by 10 per the mmol to cmol conversion). The downloaded data has a legend that goes from 0-392 and the WMS version goes from 0-852 (viewed in QGIS).

Are the values for band 1 actually in cmol(c)/kg or is there something I have to do to the data after loading into QGIS.

I am a bit new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you indicate how you downloaded the 0.05m depth CEC map, which system (portal, file system, webservice-WCS)?

Add data sources should be in: `mmol(c)/kg`

The units are documented in this FAQ: https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids

It was noticed that the units on the WMS abstract are incorrect ( cmolc/kg). If you could give extra details it would help

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! I used this link:https://data.isric.org/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/5333b1af-7620-407f-8bca-2303fc5c7288

Comment: This should be the record for the new soilgrids 2.0 https://data.isric.org/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/713396fc-1687-11ea-a7c0-a0481ca9e724

Comment: Thanks. That looks like the WMS map. There is no direct download for this?

Comment: Check the FAQ you will the downliad info  there